# Max-height no respecting css transistion

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a CSS transistion where When I click on a button it fades out and disappears to which another element will take it's place.

I've nearly completed it, however. When applying the class .hide to the button it "jumps" (the height property is not to be touched until the opacity is done). The max-height does not seem to respect the css transition property I've set in the css.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/zwzNXM?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<div class="app-profession">
  <button id="one" class="add-profession" onclick="func()">
    <img/>
    Click me!
  </button>

  <div id="two" key="pickArea" class="pick-area">
    Here! 2
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
button.add-profession {
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    font-family: 'Verdana';
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    outline-style: none;

    border: none;
    border-radius: em(0);

    opacity: 1;
    background: lightblue;

    img {
        margin-right: em(5);
        content: url('static/images/add_cross_white.png');
        height: em(30);
    }

    transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out 0s, max-height 0s linear 2s, padding 0s ease-in-out 2s;
    &.hide {
        opacity: 0;
        max-height: 0; // <--- here
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    &:hover {
        background-color: red;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.pick-area {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  background-color: green;

    opacity: 0;
    max-height: 0em;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 16px;

  transition: all 2s linear 2s;
    &.show {
        max-height: 500px;

        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
function func() {
  document.getElementById('one').classList.add('hide');
  document.getElementById('two').classList.add('show');
}
```

Comment: Is this how it should be  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVgpKG

Comment: @LGSon Indeed, post an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `max-height` to the `button.add-profession` class it will stop jumping

```
button.add-profession {
    width: 500px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    max-height: 60px;             /*  added property  */
    ....
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVgpKG)